# How to call all my images from resources in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I saved some jpg's in my resources to use later in my code. I am trying to call them but I'm having troubles with my syntax.  Any suggestions? My code:

**Dim dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo("My.Resources")
    Dim imgs = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList**

I received the error: **An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'E:....etc'**

Thanks in advance

Comment: `My.Resources` is not a folder.  `Dim someImage = My.Resources.RubberDuck`  assuming of course they were added to Resources as a resource and not just copied to something somewhere

Comment: If you want all resources into an object that you can iterate, Dim lstRes = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)

Comment: I ended up using a different method but thank you for your suggestions!